# What is the relationship between bash and xterm?

Tags: bash, xterm

I read, that bash and xterm is not the same. Bash is a so called shell and xterm a so called virtual terminal. But from my limited perspective I do not get the difference, which makes a difference. It seems to me to be a difference like between granny smith and golden delicious rather than apples and elephants, could some one try to make it clear and point to key terms?

Comment: have you read: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/117549 ?

Comment: for starters, look at `xterm -e csh`

Comment: not yet, have not found this one, tried the man pages integrated within linux